# Rolling ewma in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm trying to compute ewma in a rolling fashion, just like rolling mean, std etc... The code below does not work, I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 5))
pd.rolling_apply(arg=a[0], 
                 func=lambda x: pd.ewma(x, span=10), 
                 window=10)
```

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: what version of pandas are you running?

Comment: 0.22 ..........

Comment: no clue what the dots are for but you have my answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rolling_apply` is deprecated in pandas 0.23 (current release)

To do EWMA stuff use [`DataFrame.ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html)

```
a.ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()
```